# Filtering Rows with Duplicate ID using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following Data frame

```
ID <- c("0141-np66-knw0", "0141-np66-knw0", "02y9-1hhy-0qn8", "06ya-mut5-ps3q","06ya-mut5-ps3q","06ya-mut5-ps3q")
town <- c("Town A","Town A","Town B","Town C", "Town D","Town D")
village <- c("Village F","Village K", "Village W", "Village H", "Village O", "Village Z")
towns <- data.frame(ID, town, village)

              ID   town   village
1 0141-np66-knw0 Town A Village F
2 0141-np66-knw0 Town A Village K
3 02y9-1hhy-0qn8 Town B Village W
4 06ya-mut5-ps3q Town C Village H
5 06ya-mut5-ps3q Town D Village O
6 06ya-mut5-ps3q Town D Village Z
```

In the end, I want 1 data frame  that contains only distinct rows of the column ID

Expected Output

```
              ID   town   village
1 0141-np66-knw0 Town A Village F
3 02y9-1hhy-0qn8 Town B Village W
4 06ya-mut5-ps3q Town C Village H
```

Comment: do you mean the rest of the rows, not columns? `split(towns, duplicated(towns$ID))`

Comment: I've edited the question to show the expected output

Comment: `towns %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: You're specifically trying to get rid of the rest of those rows (which have unique data in them)? If you don't care about the town and village values, just drop them from your dataset and call `unique` on it.